# T-SQL Execution Plan showing undefined expression?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, expression, sql-execution-plan

I want to start building a tool that more or less shows you the data-lineage of a query using parsing of the execution plan - so that you get information of the form:

Column A of Table XY was computed by taking Column B of Table XZ and adding Column C of Table PL

You get the idea :)

Now, when I tried some queries and looking at the corresponding execution plans, I ran into the issue that there was a random expression present without any definition as to how it is computed.

It appeared in a nested Loop OuterReferences Section, I queried just one table and seemingly performed an index scan followed by a key lookup. When "joining" those 2, the index scan and the key lookup, the query plan XML just showed:

```
ColumnReference = Column="Expr1020"
```

I tried searching the XML-File for another occurrence of `Expr1020`, but there were none.

Now, my question is: can anybody explain why this happens or what exactly happens in the query plan?

I figured every expression used should have a definition that is in some way based on the columns used, but this one is never referenced again :/

Comment: There are quite a few cases where the XML plan has missing nodes and expressions. Without seeing your actual plan it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably for nested loops prefetch.

See [this article](https://www.sql.kiwi/2013/08/sql-server-internals-nested-loops-prefetching.html) for more details

> The output also shows that the mystery node uses an expression
> labelled [Expr1004] with a type of binary(24). This expression is
> shown in regular showplan output as an outer reference (correlated
> parameter) of the nested loops join: ...
> No definition is provided for this expression, and no other explicit
> reference is made to it anywhere else in the plan
>
> ...
>
> The prefetch operator can issue multiple asynchronous reads based on
> outer-input values. It uses a small memory buffer to keep track, and
> to save index leaf page information in particular.
>
> A reference to this information was seen earlier as the outer
> reference binary (24) expression label Expr1004. My understanding is
> that the leaf page information is used on the inner side of the join
> in hints to the storage engine to prevent duplicated effort by the
> normal read-ahead mechanisms. It may also be used for other purposes.

The XML execution plan doesn't show all details from the actual compiled plan. The actual compiled plan can contain additional properties and even entire operator nodes that the XML plan does not display.

Comment: Thank you so much!
A quick additional question if you don´t mind - is it safe to assume that logically, the XML-Plan contains all the necessary information? As far as i understand, the scenario that i ran into now would give me an Expression that isn´t described anywhere, but is also only used for "internal" optimization. So i guess the question is, will the execution plan also leave out nodes/information that would be relevant for my actual result in regards to WHAT is in the result, in comparison to HOW it got there?

Comment: @bochner - I think what you are trying to do is mostly viable. I can think of two examples where it won't work. **1** `DECLARE @T TABLE(X INT UNIQUE); INSERT @T DEFAULT VALUES; DECLARE @X INT; SELECT * FROM @T WHERE (X = @X) OR (@X IS NULL AND X IS NULL) ; SELECT * FROM @T WHERE (X = @X) `  - these queries return different results but the execution plans appear the same as the `IS` / `EQ` distinction isn't exposed in this case

Comment: **2** `DECLARE @T TABLE(X INT UNIQUE); SELECT SUM(X) FROM @T;  SELECT SUM(X) FROM @T GROUP BY ()` returns different results as vector aggregate vs scalar aggregate and again this isn't shown in the plan

Comment: you may well come across other such cases in this project though where the execution plan misses out something, neither of the above affect column lineage though so maybe these don't cause a problem to you anyway